# How to properly bind a ListBoxItem in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, listview

I have a listbox and I want to iterate over a collection of Bars in my Foo-object.

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars}" >
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

This is the datatemplate I want to use.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Bar}">
        <Label Content="hello stackoverflow" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If I snoop (--> examine by using the tool Snoop) my application, I notice that the **entire collection** of Bars is bound to the ContentControl, **in stead of just 1**.

How can I properly bind so the iteration over the collection goes fine?

Answer (score 8):

You can just set the DataTemplate, and WPF does all the work. Set the ItemsSource to a list of `Bar` items, and then define a DataTemplate for `Bar` items.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo.Bars}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Bar}">
            <Label Content="hello stackoverflow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

You could also set the ItemsTemplate directly by using `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` instead of `<ListBox.Resources>`

See [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: @Default Yeah, that link as rotted away and I can't find a replacement sorry. It was just an article talking about bindings in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

First add your namespace to the `Window` element (Intellisense) :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourenamespace"
```

Then the following `XAML` ( in `Window.Resources` is a clean way to do it ) :

```
   <Window.Resources>

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Foo}"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template" >
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bar}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Place the `Listbox` :

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataProvider}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Bars}" ItemTemplate="DynamicResource Template" />
```

But, it depends on your code-behind object, you have to set a constructor to initialise public properties within your object which are [ObservableCollection<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) preferably (There is some restriction rules with object instance in `XAML`).

Comment: I suggest you to type your object code in your question. There was some syntax error in my answer, i correct it ( Resource, not Resouce, forgotten GridView, i'am typing it all with the hand... ).

Comment: actually I'm using a ListBox. I first posted ListView, but I edited that.